# Using the reduce function on a multidimensional array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, average, reduce

So i have a particular array, that has 2 seperate arrays withing itself. What I am looking to do is to average together those 2 seperate arrays, so for instance, if i have my original array such as `[(2,3,4),(4,5,6)]` and I want an output array like `[3,5]`, how would i do this? My attempt to do this is as follows:

```
averages = reduce(sum(array)/len(array), [array])
```

Comment: Your data structure is an array of tuples, not an array of arrays. This shouldn't affect this problem, but can have a major effect due to the differences between the data types.

Comment: Well, how would i deal with a problem? that difference between tuples and ints is what cause my attempted solution to not work. the error message was "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reduce` is not a good choice here.  Just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [(2,3,4),(4,5,6)]
>>> [sum(t)/len(t) for t in a]
[3, 5]
```

Note that `/` is integer division by default in python2.

If you have `numpy` available, you have a nicer option:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> a.mean(axis=1)
array([ 3.,  5.])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), [(2,3,4),(4,5,6)])
[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comphrehesion:

```
data = [(2,3,4),(4,5,6)]
averages = [ sum(tup)/len(tup) for tup in data ]
```